# jquery click and cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, greasemonkey

I have a greasemonkey script to run in a specific website. 
The objective is make click in a specific button,
remove the cookie (**Tthe website sets the cookie on click, i have to remove the cookie before to make the new click, but the trouble is the cookie is not sets with jquery click**
)
then reload the page.
And repeat the process.

But, jquery click method don't sets the cookie but the human click yes

here is the code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        name
// @namespace   someName
// @include     http://www.example.com/*
// @version     0.1
// @grant       all
// @require     http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js
// ==/UserScript==


function del_cookie(name) {
    document.cookie = name +
    '=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT;path=/;';
} 


function fnc(){

 try{
   $("#elemenID").click();
   del_cookie("elemID");
   location.reload();
  }catch(e){
        alert(e.toString());
   }
}


$(document).ready(function(){

    window.setTimeout(fnc, 10000);   

})
```

Comment: **Quote:** _"The objetive is make click in a specific button, then remove the cookie (the button sets the cookie on click )"_ ~ You want to add and remove the same cookie with the same click?   Please clarify your functional description.

Comment: The website sets the cookie on click, i have to remove the cookie before to make the new click.

Comment: but the jquery click doesn't sets the cookie...

Comment: Can you show the onclick function for button?

Comment: yes. I have added the js from deobfuscator.

Comment: Holy mother of god, you need to turn that into a [SSCE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSCE) man

Comment: @Asad wrong [SSCE](http://sscce.org/) link man. `=]`

Comment: [Sorry, but I'm voting to close this whole mess](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Actually, the deobfuscator output was very helpful and may have provided a crucial clue -- if my pending answer works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this, and the problem was the time factor. 
here is the final greasemonkey script.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        name
// @namespace   someName
// @include     http://www.example.com/*
// @version     0.1
// @grant       all
// @require     http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

function del_cookie(name) {
            document.cookie = name +
            '=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT;path=/;';
  } 


function fnc(){
 $("#id").click();
}

function fnc2(){
 del_cookie("cookieID");
}

function fnc3(){
    location.reload();
}

$(function(){


        window.setTimeout(fnc2, 10000);   
        window.setTimeout(fnc, 20000);   
        window.setTimeout(fnc3, 30000);
})
```